# Linking to a view multiple times from tabar

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to setup my application, so I can have multiple tabbar items link to the same view controller,but pass in different parameters to setup the view appropriately.

**My setup is as follows**
    TabBarController
        NavbarController - TabBarItem1
            PeopleView
        NavbarController - TabBarItem2
            ContentView

**I want my setup to**

```
TabBarController
    NavbarController1 - TabBarItem1
        Links to: PeopleView
    NavbarController2 - TabBarItem2
        Links to: ContentView
    NavbarController3 - TabBarItem3
        Links to: ContentView //Same VC as TabBaritem 2.
```

I have tried putting the code below in my appdelage and implementing the UITabBarControllerDelegate, but my application always crashes with this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [UITabBarController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fce7c0'
```

**Here is the code I have implemented:**

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MediaList *mediaList = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SB_MediaList"];
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mediaList animated:YES];


}
```

More than anything I would like to proper way to accomplish this to avoid having three classes and screens for the exact same functionality.

Sorry if this is a very basic question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this approach instead,

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    DemoViewController *demoView = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoView"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:demoView];
    NSMutableArray *viewsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];

    if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {
        //Load data for your demoView instance for tabBarItem 1
    } else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 2) {
        //Load data for your demoView instance for tabBarItem 2
    }

    [viewsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:viewController.tabBarItem.tag withObject:navigationController];
    self.viewControllers = viewsArray;
}
```

I uploaded the project here https://github.com/coch3/iOS---STCK-Q-19056515

Comment: I am getting an issue saying the navigationcontroller not found on object type AppDelegate.

Comment: do I need a segue setup first for that ?

Comment: I guess the good news is that it's no longer crashing with this code ;)  The bad news is it's not navigating to the correct page.  Here is the updated code I used..
    tabVC = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    [self.tabVC.navigationController pushViewController:mediaList animated:YES];

}

Comment: From your original approach , have you double checked of having `@"SB_MediaList"` as a Storyboard ID on your `@"Main"` Storyboard ?

Comment: yes.. The identity of the page is StoryBoard Id = SB_MediaList.  The name of the entire storyboard is Main.  Am I right to have the tabcontroller at the front of everything as the initial view controller ?  I assume that is ok..

Comment: I just edited my anwser, hope this new approach helps I will also upload the code

Comment: Just uploaded the github link, hope this approach fits your needs

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.   It's close to what I am looking for, but not quite.  Here is a sample project of what I am trying:https://github.com/mdaymond/stack

Comment: This worked very well, but it looks like there is a strange side effect.  Before I had a method in my delagate to customize the tab bar.  It sets images for selected/unselected states.  Now when I select one of the new items they lose their images on the tab bar.  Any ideas ?  I have tried moving the method into the new MainTabBarController, but that hasn't helped so far...

Comment: I've narrowed it down further it looks like these two calls cause me to lose my tabbar customization I have setup in my delegate.            [viewsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:viewController.tabBarItem.tag withObject:navigationController];
        self.viewControllers = viewsArray;

Comment: Right, what is really doing is creating again the elements of the navigation bar item selected, so any customization should be done there again or perhaps having a global customization method that also should be applied there. I will try to improve the answer

Comment: I was able to move my customization code into the maintabbar class.   This allows me to see the images on tab bar items all the time  but because I need to call my tab bar customization method on every didselectviewcontroller I am getting a flicker when I load the view on those links that run through the method.  Let me know if I am being clear enough or if I should edit my post to clarify.

Comment: you've been a huge help and you've answered my initial question quite well.   Since what I am seeing right now seems to potentially be a separate issue I've opened a new ticket here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/19060566/2804909.     It better describes the current issue.